# laravel does not allow external video play

Tags: laravel, video, embed

i have a server nginx and save my video file in it.

I want to play those in My another website which create with laravel

my link in nginx like

```
http://1.1.1.1/video.mp4
```

my controller like

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $url = url('http://1.1.1.1/video.mp4');
    
    return view('blog.index', compact('url'));
}
```

and my section video blade like

```
<video poster="video.jpg" src={{ $url }} ></video>
```

when i put internal link like /video/video.mp4 it work fine, but with http://1.1.1.1/video.mp4 it doesnt work!!!!

any hlp????

Comment: Do you have online web space to show a demo/page of your problem? You have many stages so it's not clear what _"It doesn't work"_ means here **exactly**... For example: Is the video loading data (buffering) but not showing a picture? Are you getting a file not found error? Is that what _"It doesn't work"_ means here?

Comment: hi . I find the problem . http doesn't support with my host and I have to enable https in nginx server. thank anyway

Comment: No worries. I noticed that possible issue of mixing HTTP with HTTPS. That's why showing your link and us checking if it started with `https://` would help solve the problem... PS: Post an Answer so it helps others needing a solution.